# something like Interface

Tags: c#, interface, static-methods

we want use sometihng like interface for force to  write some static methods (create,delete,update).What can we use like interface but can use static methods

edit: we have project and we use  entity framework for DAL.For example Product table.We think we create PruductDAL class and we add Create(Product product) method Update(Product product) method Delete(int id) method and GetById(int id) method.And we think create static methods for dont use new ProductDAL() and dont create instance of class .Just Product.Create(product).

We code with 4-5 person and i think we must force everyone to write class contains crud methods.

Which way we must follow ?

Comment: An interface is not a mechanism to "force someone to write methods".

Comment: you could use reflection to check whether the method is there and is static

Comment: Also, in what context would this be useful?  You only need to write a static method if you're going to call it.  And if you try to call it and it hasn't been written, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Try to write interface, and then static class with singletone of this inteface. It's hard to answer because you have not given enough details

Comment: It sounds like you want `Create`,`Delete`, `Update` operations implemented on an entity class. That's bad design, since persistence shouldn't be the responsibility of an entity.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to force child class implementing some static methods.

I don't think this is an correct OO concept and mostly you have a problem in your design. But if you really want to do this. you can have a base class that using reflection to check whether the client class defines static methods you need and throw runtime error. There is no way to do this in compile time.

But still, your requirement smells like bad design.

Comment: `abstract`/`virtual` class methods are perfectly fine in principle. C# just doesn't support them. In this specific case it's probably bad design, but you can't generalize that.

Answer (score 0):

`Static` member doesn't make part of the *instance* but of the *type*, so you can not do what you want in OOP way.

If you want to "force" to write static methods, use a `static class`, but you loose inheritance capability. The `static method`, in my vision of the code when I see it, is a signal of *stateless stuff*. So using `static class`, if the set of static methods is actually what you want to get, could be affordable solution for you.

There is also, of course, an obvious solution: talk with the people and define design goals.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Statics can have state...a static class can have static fields and properties.

Comment: @MrLane: correct. I never say that it's not. I' m talking about an *intent* (signal) it makes to a consumer. That is.

Comment: Thats fair enough, alot of devs would agree with you I guess, but I just never got the whole "statics are for when there is no state" line. To me static classes imply global rather than stateless classes.

Comment: @MrLane: this is just "feeling" that you get looking on static function. Ssomething that executes the stuff, but **usually** doesn't store something.

Answer (score 0):

```
class EnsureStaticMethodsGetWritten
{
  Action ensure1 = ThatStaticClass.BetterImplementThis;
  Func<Customer, bool> ensure2 = ThatStaticClass.BetterImplementThisToo;
}
```

This class won't compile until that `ThatStaticClass` has those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your DAL using static methods. I have always created EntityFramework DAL classes as wrappers around my EntityContext and implemented all of my LINQ and Lambdas in there. The EntityContext gets created in my DAL class constructor and I dispose of the EntityContext in my DAL classes Dispose(). Each query is implemented in a seperate method and returns IQuerable so I can chain queries. Then I can use my DAL in my business code like this:

```
using(IMyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    IQueryable<User> query = context.RetrieveUsersByRole("Software Developers");

    List<User> developerUsers = query.ToList(); // Query gets executed here

    foreach(User dev in developerUsers)
        dev.Salary = 100000000;

    context.SaveChanges()
}
```

This isnt exactly DDD but it does provides seperation between the EntityFramework and the Business Logic and allows queries to be reusable/chained. There is no statics (I rarely ever use static classes/methods).

EDIT: This is Unit of Work style approach, not a CRUD/Repository style of approach.